# Jackson: Use default (de)serializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to (de)serialize an object that has a property with a type that comes from a maven dependency, so I can't change the class of this type.
The class of this type has a `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` annotation.

However, I want to use the default serializer and deserialzer, because the custom serializer writes an array instead of an object. Is there a way, using annotations, to tell jackson to use the default (de)serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the annotations using Jackson's mixins feature.

In the following example, any attempt at deserializing to a `CustomerObj` will result in an exception due to its defective `Builder`:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = CustomerObj.class)
public class CustomerObj {
    public String name;
    public int age;

    public CustomerObj build() {
        throw new RuntimeException("JsonDeserializer invoked");
    }
}
```

Create a mixin with a `JsonDeserialize` annotation that disables the broken builder:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = java.lang.Void.class)
public static abstract class CustomerMixin { }
```

Register the mixin on the `ObjectMapper` instance:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.addMixIn(CustomerObj.class, CustomerMixin.class);
```

Enjoy working deserialization:

```
final String json = "{\"name\":\"Brian\",\"age\":41}";
CustomerObj customer = om.readValue(json, CustomerObj.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, that'll probably work for the deserializer, but @JsonSerialize doesn't have the builder option.

Comment: @david : The mixin functionality applies to all annotations, so you should consult the documentation and figure out which option to override for `@JsonSerialize`. My guess is that you need to override `using` with `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.None.class`, but look into it.

Comment: Ok, I think I should have made my problem more clear.
The problem is not where to overwrite the (de)serializer, but which one to use.
I tried @JsonSerialize(using = JsonSerializer.None.class), but then the Serializer annotated in the source is used.
When I use a custom serializer and use @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class) it works.